# Preload streaming with avplayer/avaudioplayer

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer

I have a problem with avplayer/avaudioplayer. I'm using these classes for streaming aac or pls audio content (radio).

I would like to preload specified time od content and play streaming with delay, for example 20 seconds. it occurs that when I turn on, for example, airplane mode and network is lost, player should play from this moment 20 seconds while it stops.

I use this code for mp4 from network and it seems to works but when i change this for aac/pls streaming...it's loading and everything seems to work but when I turn on airplane mode, it stops immidiately...

is it possible to keep in buffer content and play with delay with streaming?

My code:

```
@interface AVFViewController ()
{
    AVPlayer *player;
    PlayerView *playerView;
    id t

imeObserver;
    NSInteger _playing;
}
@end

@implementation AVFViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self playURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://nba.cdn.turner.com/nba/big/channels/top_plays/2012/02/03/20120203_top10.nba_nba_ipad.mp4"]];
    //http://acdn.smcloud.net/t042-1_mp3.pls
    //http://nba.cdn.turner.com/nba/big/channels/top_plays/2012/02/03/20120203_top10.nba_nba_ipad.mp4
}

- (void)playURL:(NSURL *)videoURL
{
    if (!player) {
        player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
        playerView = [[PlayerView alloc] init];
        [playerView setPlayer:player];
        playerView.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 20, 20);
        playerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        playerView.alpha = 1;
        [self.view addSubview:playerView];

        [player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kTimeRangesKVO];

    }
    [player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:[[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:videoURL]];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context 
{
    if (kTimeRangesKVO == context) {
        NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray *)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
        if (timeRanges && [timeRanges count]) {
        NSArray *loadedTimeRanges = [[player currentItem] loadedTimeRanges];
        CMTimeRange timeRange = [[loadedTimeRanges objectAtIndex:0] CMTimeRangeValue];
        float startSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.start);
        float durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration);
        NSTimeInterval result = startSeconds + durationSeconds;
        NSLog(@"duration is %f",result);

            if (!_playing && result > 20) {
                [player.currentItem seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1)];
                [player play];
                _playing = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```